# Python in Maya, syntax error for UV script

Tags: python, assets, maya, alembic

I'm trying to assign root UVs to an alembic Maya XGen file, so that I can give the XGen fur the colours of the mesh underneath in Unreal Engine. I have a jaguar mesh with UVs assigned, and am trying to transfer them to the alembic groom. I'm using the Epic code, however I keep getting an "# Error: invalid syntax# " notification. I'm using Maya 2022. I'm not very experienced at all in programming, so I would hugely appreciate it if anyone is able to spot what is causing the code to crash. Thank you so much in advance!

Epic documentation: https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/WorkingWithContent/Hair/XgenGuidelines/

---

```
from maya import cmds
from maya import OpenMaya
import os

def create_root_uv_attribute(curves_group, mesh_node, uv_set='map1'):
'''
Create "groom_root_uv" attribute on group of curves.
'''

# check curves group
if not cmds.objExists(curves_group):
raise RuntimeError('Group not found: "{}"'.format(curves_group))

# get curves in group
curve_shapes = cmds.listRelatives(curves_group, shapes=True, noIntermediate=True)
curve_shapes = cmds.ls(curve_shapes, type='nurbsCurve')
if not curve_shapes:
raise RuntimeError('Invalid curves group. No nurbs-curves found in group.')
else:
print "found curves"
print curve_shapes

# get curve roots
points = list()
for curve_shape in curve_shapes:
point = cmds.pointPosition('{}.cv[0]'.format(curve_shape), world=True)
points.append(point)

# get uvs
values = list()
uvs = find_closest_uv_point(points, mesh_node, uv_set=uv_set)
for u, v in uvs:
values.append([u, v, 0])
#print (str(u) + " , " + str(v) )

# create attribute
name = 'groom_root_uv'
cmds.addAttr(curves_group, ln=name, dt='vectorArray')
cmds.addAttr(curves_group, ln='{}_AbcGeomScope'.format(name), dt='string')
cmds.addAttr(curves_group, ln='{}_AbcType'.format(name), dt='string')

cmds.setAttr('{}.{}'.format(curves_group, name), len(values), *values, type='vectorArray')
cmds.setAttr('{}.{}_AbcGeomScope'.format(curves_group, name), 'uni', type='string')
cmds.setAttr('{}.{}_AbcType'.format(curves_group, name), 'vector2', type='string')

return uvs

def find_closest_uv_point(points, mesh_node, uv_set='map1'):
'''
Find mesh UV-coordinates at given points.
'''

# check mesh
if not cmds.objExists(mesh_node):
raise RuntimeError('Node not found: "{}"'.format(mesh_node))

# check uv_set
uv_sets = cmds.polyUVSet(mesh_node, q=True, allUVSets=True)
if uv_set not in uv_sets:
raise RuntimeError('Invalid uv_set provided: "{}"'.format(uv_set))

# get mesh as dag-path
selection_list = OpenMaya.MSelectionList()
selection_list.add(mesh_node)

mesh_dagpath = OpenMaya.MDagPath()
selection_list.getDagPath(0, mesh_dagpath)
mesh_dagpath.extendToShape()

# get mesh function set
fn_mesh = OpenMaya.MFnMesh(mesh_dagpath)

uvs = list()
for i in range(len(points)):

script_util = OpenMaya.MScriptUtil()
script_util.createFromDouble(0.0, 0.0)
uv_point = script_util.asFloat2Ptr()

point = OpenMaya.MPoint(*points[i])
fn_mesh.getUVAtPoint(point, uv_point, OpenMaya.MSpace.kWorld, uv_set)

u = OpenMaya.MScriptUtil.getFloat2ArrayItem(uv_point, 0, 0)
v = OpenMaya.MScriptUtil.getFloat2ArrayItem(uv_point, 0, 1)

uvs.append((u, v))

return uvs

def abc_export(filepath, node=None, start_frame=1, end_frame=1, data_format='otawa', uv_write=True):

job_command = '-frameRange {} {} '.format(start_frame, end_frame)
job_command += '-dataFormat {} '.format(data_format)

job_command += '-attr groom_root_uv '

if uv_write:
job_command += '-uvWrite '

job_command += '-root {} '.format(node)

job_command += '-file {} '.format(filepath)

cmds.AbcExport(verbose=True, j=job_command)

def main():

export_directory = 'D:/Projects/Jaguar_Groom/Jag_Groom_copied_14_07/New/Maya_Xgen'
hair_file = os.path.join(export_directory, 'hair_export.abc')
curve_top_group= 'alembic_curves:jaguar_main_fur_splineDescription'
uv_mesh='retopo_furmesh'

create_root_uv_attribute( curve_top_group , uv_mesh)
abc_export(hair_file, curve_top_group)

main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take the time to format your code such that it is indented properly.

Answer (score 0):

This runs fine for me with one modification. I updated both print statements in create_root_uv_attribute(...) to have braces ().

By default Maya 2022 uses Python 3 while this code seems to be written for Python 2 e.g. print 'Hello World' is valid in 2 but invalid in 3, print('Hello World') is expected.

You can launch Maya 2022 in Python 2 by following the instructions in the link below:

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2022/ENU/Maya-Scripting/files/GUID-C0F27A50-3DD6-454C-A4D1-9E3C44B3C990-htm.html

I've included the updated code below.

```
from maya import cmds
from maya import OpenMaya
import os

def create_root_uv_attribute(curves_group, mesh_node, uv_set='map1'):
    '''
    Create "groom_root_uv" attribute on group of curves.
    '''

    # check curves group
    if not cmds.objExists(curves_group):
        raise RuntimeError('Group not found: "{}"'.format(curves_group))

    # get curves in group
    curve_shapes = cmds.listRelatives(curves_group, shapes=True, noIntermediate=True)
    curve_shapes = cmds.ls(curve_shapes, type='nurbsCurve')
    if not curve_shapes:
        raise RuntimeError('Invalid curves group. No nurbs-curves found in group.')
    else:
        print("found curves")
        print(curve_shapes)

    # get curve roots
    points = list()
    for curve_shape in curve_shapes:
        point = cmds.pointPosition('{}.cv[0]'.format(curve_shape), world=True)
        points.append(point)

    # get uvs
    values = list()
    uvs = find_closest_uv_point(points, mesh_node, uv_set=uv_set)
    for u, v in uvs:
        values.append([u, v, 0])

    # create attribute
    name = 'groom_root_uv'
    cmds.addAttr(curves_group, ln=name, dt='vectorArray')
    cmds.addAttr(curves_group, ln='{}_AbcGeomScope'.format(name), dt='string')
    cmds.addAttr(curves_group, ln='{}_AbcType'.format(name), dt='string')

    cmds.setAttr('{}.{}'.format(curves_group, name), len(values), *values, type='vectorArray')
    cmds.setAttr('{}.{}_AbcGeomScope'.format(curves_group, name), 'uni', type='string')
    cmds.setAttr('{}.{}_AbcType'.format(curves_group, name), 'vector2', type='string')

    return uvs

def find_closest_uv_point(points, mesh_node, uv_set='map1'):
    '''
    Find mesh UV-coordinates at given points.
    '''

    # check mesh
    if not cmds.objExists(mesh_node):
        raise RuntimeError('Node not found: "{}"'.format(mesh_node))

    # check uv_set
    uv_sets = cmds.polyUVSet(mesh_node, q=True, allUVSets=True)
    if uv_set not in uv_sets:
        raise RuntimeError('Invalid uv_set provided: "{}"'.format(uv_set))

    # get mesh as dag-path
    selection_list = OpenMaya.MSelectionList()
    selection_list.add(mesh_node)

    mesh_dagpath = OpenMaya.MDagPath()
    selection_list.getDagPath(0, mesh_dagpath)
    mesh_dagpath.extendToShape()

    # get mesh function set
    fn_mesh = OpenMaya.MFnMesh(mesh_dagpath)

    uvs = list()
    for i in range(len(points)):

        script_util = OpenMaya.MScriptUtil()
        script_util.createFromDouble(0.0, 0.0)
        uv_point = script_util.asFloat2Ptr()

        point = OpenMaya.MPoint(*points[i])
        fn_mesh.getUVAtPoint(point, uv_point, OpenMaya.MSpace.kWorld, uv_set)

        u = OpenMaya.MScriptUtil.getFloat2ArrayItem(uv_point, 0, 0)
        v = OpenMaya.MScriptUtil.getFloat2ArrayItem(uv_point, 0, 1)

        uvs.append((u, v))

    return uvs

def abc_export(filepath, node=None, start_frame=1, end_frame=1, data_format='otawa', uv_write=True):

    job_command = '-frameRange {} {} '.format(start_frame, end_frame)
    job_command += '-dataFormat {} '.format(data_format)

    job_command += '-attr groom_root_uv '

    if uv_write:
        job_command += '-uvWrite '

    job_command += '-root {} '.format(node)   

    job_command += '-file {} '.format(filepath) 

    cmds.AbcExport(verbose=True, j=job_command)

def main():

    export_directory = 'D:/Projects/Jaguar_Groom/Jag_Groom_copied_14_07/New/Maya_Xgen'
    hair_file = os.path.join(export_directory, 'hair_export.abc')
    curve_top_group='alembic_curves:jaguar_main_fur_splineDescription'
    uv_mesh='retopo_furmesh'

    create_root_uv_attribute( curve_top_group , uv_mesh)
    abc_export(hair_file, curve_top_group)

main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution! I wondered if it was the print statements tripping me up - really appreciate you fixing the code for me!

Comment: Anytime! Easy enough to miss but I hope it helped.